# How can I sort a Google Charts DataTable and have the sorting expand to other columns?

Tags: javascript, sorting, charts, google-visualization

I'm working on creating a Pareto chart using a google charts ComboChart. I'm working through instructions found on this site:

http://ajhaupt.blogspot.com/2013/01/pareto-charts-with-google-charts.html

I've been looking for a few days and haven't found anything on here that solves the issue.

Here is the section of my code (var rows is received like this: `"{"startingIssue":21,"manualIssue":8,"powerIssue":7,"trimmerHeadIssue":15,"qualityIssue":3,"customerSupportIssue":1,"noiseIssue":1,"vibrationIssue":1,"ergonomicIssue":3}"`)

```
var rows = xmlhttp.responseText;

var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'Category');
data.addColumn('number', 'Frequency');
data.addColumn('number', 'Pctg');
alert(rows);
var jsonData = JSON.parse(rows);
//alert(jsonData['start']);

var sum = 0;
for (var key in jsonData) {
  sum += jsonData[key];
}
var total = sum;

var accum = 0;
for (var key in jsonData) {
  data.addRows([
    [(key), jsonData[key], accum + (jsonData[key] / sum) * 100]
  ]);
  accum = accum + (jsonData[key] / sum) * 100;
}
data.sort({
  column: 1,
  desc: true
});
//data.sort({column: 2, desc: true});

// Calculate the accumulating percentages
// and add them into a new column in each row

// Add the title row at the beginning of dataSet
// ('unshift' is not supported in IE8 and earlier)
//data.unshift( dataTitle );

var options = {
  title: 'Pareto chart',
  legend: {
    position: 'none'
  }, // no legend
  // Create two vertical axes taking its titles from the first row
  vAxes: [{
    title: dataSet1[0][1],
    minValue: 0
  }, {
    title: dataSet1[0][2],
    minValue: 0,
    maxValue: 100
  }],
  hAxis: {
    title: dataSet1[0][0]
  },
  backgroundColor: {
    strokeWidth: 2
  }, // to get a nice box
  seriesType: "bars", // the standard chart type
  // the second data column should be of type 'line' and should be associated with the second vertical axis
  series: {
    1: {
      type: "line",
      targetAxisIndex: 1
    }
  },
};

var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(
  document.getElementById('chart_div'));

chart.draw(data, options);
```

I've tried to sort the data prior to adding it to a DataTable so I could take advantage of the sorting/arrays directly in javascript, but no matter how I do it, the graph always turns out to be incorrect as shown here:

[pareto chart output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rP6G4.jpg)

The blue bars have been sorted descending as they should, however the red line should correspond to the total cumulative percentage moving from left to right.

I feel like this is a very relevant question for anyone using Google Charts and wanting to properly sort their data and expand it to other columns.

I've also tried different ways of calculating the cumulative percentage, however none have gotten me as close as the method I'm currently using.

Answer (score 2):

the data must be sorted before calculating the cumulative percentage

there are several ways to accomplish,
but sticking with tools from google,
load each column independently

1) load frequency column
2) sort frequency column desc
3) use [`group()`](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#google_visualization_data_group) to get total
4) load percentage column

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var jsonData = {"startingIssue":21,"manualIssue":8,"powerIssue":7,"trimmerHeadIssue":15,"qualityIssue":3,"customerSupportIssue":1,"noiseIssue":1,"vibrationIssue":1,"ergonomicIssue":3};

    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Category');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Frequency');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Pctg');

    // 1) load frequency column
    for (var key in jsonData) {
      data.addRows([
        [(key), jsonData[key], null]
      ]);
    }

    // 2) sort frequency column
    data.sort({
      column: 1,
      desc: true
    });

    // 3) get total
    var dataSum = google.visualization.data.group(
      data,
      [{column: 0, type: 'string', modifier: function () {return '';}}],
      [{column: 1, type: 'number', aggregation: google.visualization.data.sum}]
    );

    // 4) load percentage column
    var accum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
      accum += data.getValue(i, 1);
      data.setValue(i, 2, (accum / dataSum.getValue(0, 1)) * 100);
    }

    var options = {
      title: 'Pareto chart',
      legend: {
        position: 'none'
      }, // no legend
      // Create two vertical axes taking its titles from the first row
      vAxes: [{
        //title: dataSet1[0][1],
        minValue: 0
      }, {
        //title: dataSet1[0][2],
        minValue: 0,
        maxValue: 100
      }],
      hAxis: {
        //title: dataSet1[0][0]
      },
      backgroundColor: {
        strokeWidth: 2
      }, // to get a nice box
      seriesType: "bars", // the standard chart type
      // the second data column should be of type 'line' and should be associated with the second vertical axis
      series: {
        1: {
          type: "line",
          targetAxisIndex: 1
        }
      }
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  },
  packages:['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

*further clarification:*

the cumulative percentage needs to be calculated **anytime** the table is sorted

for example, consider the following frequency rows...
`total = 24`

`category, frequency, percentage`
`A,         4,     16.667`
`B,         8,     50.000`
`C,        12,    100.000`

regardles of what column is sorted, the cumulative percentage must be re-calculated,
or it will be incorrect for that row

sort on Category, must have new %
`category, frequency, percentage`
`C,        12,     50.000`
`B,         8,     83.333`
`A,         4,    100.000`